# Sending email from the iOS sdk

Tags: ios, ios8, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

I am trying to send email from within my iOS app.

The idea is to have one class `SendMessage` which all classes use to send email from within the app. It is a subclass of `NSObject` and is a `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`

This is what the SendMessage class looks like

```
@implementation SendMessage

- (void) sendEmailFromViewController : (UIViewController *)viewController withSubject : (NSString *) subject withRecipient : (NSString *)recipient withMessage : (NSString *)message withCompletionBlock : (void(^)(void))completionBlock withFailure : (void(^)(void))failure {

    self.viewController = viewController;

    if (![MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){
        if (failure)
            failure();
    }
    else {
        MFMailComposeViewController *messageController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        messageController.mailComposeDelegate = self.viewController;
        [messageController setSubject:subject];
        [messageController setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:recipient]];
        [messageController setMessageBody:message isHTML:NO];

        [self.viewController presentModalViewController:messageController animated:YES];

    }
}

-(void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {
    [self.viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

I am trying to call the class using:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == 3) {
        SendMessage *sendFeedback = [[SendMessage alloc] init];
        [sendFeedback sendEmailFromViewController:self withSubject:@"App Feedback" withRecipient:@"ashisha@moj.io" withMessage:@"This is app feedback" withCompletionBlock:nil withFailure:nil];
    }
}
```

The problem is that although I am able to send the email, the delegate method is not being called. How do I fix it ?

Comment: set messageController.mailComposeDelegate to **self** not self.viewController;

Comment: Made the change. Same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delegate is the `UIViewController`, so implement the `mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error` delegate method there.

Comment: I just changed the SendMessage to be a subclass of UIViewController and set the messageController.mailComposeDelegate = self

Comment: You can implement the method in the view controller which has `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. You don't have to subclass it, and setting delegate to self won't work because `sendFeedback` is an instance variable and will be released out of scope.

Comment: I changed the instance variable to a property. It works now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your object `sendFeedback` is released at the end of the block.

The best solution is to create **singleton** object and than use it

In the `SendMessage.h` file add

```
+ (instancetype) sharedManager;
```

In the `SendMessage.m` file add

```
+ (instancetype) sharedManager{
    static SendMessage* instance = nil;
    if(!instance){
        instance = [[SendMessage alloc] init];
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Than you can use your **singleton** anywhere in the code

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == 3) {
        SendMessage *sendFeedback = [SendMessage sharedManager];
        [sendFeedback sendEmailFromViewController:self withSubject:@"App Feedback" withRecipient:@"ashisha@moj.io" withMessage:@"This is app feedback" withCompletionBlock:nil withFailure:nil];
    }
}
```

Also `messageController.mailComposeDelegate` must be set to **self**